# How to get only months in drop down and and set the default value as current month in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I want to display the reports in the data table dynamically after selecting the month, and by default, it will show the report of the current month.
[This is the output that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Me8.png)

Comment: You can make the months static. If you are extracting the months from the dates, you can use `intl` package

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada Can you show me? How can I extract months and display in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install package from https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install

```
DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime.now());
```

to check more formatting options, see https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: If this has worked for you, I will appreciate if you can give it a tick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a list of all the months
2. Get DateTime.now() to get the month, and set the selected month in the dropdown to that month
3. If a dataset is selected, take the month of that dataset and assign it to the selected value in the dropdown

Comment: how can I get the list of all months?

Comment: It's an incomplete answer, helped a little. Thank you